# Gatsby-Redux: Component doesn't re-render on state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, gatsby

as I was implementing [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) in my [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) project, I saw that my component doesn't re-render when the component's state changes (and yes, I was treating the state as immutable).

So I used Redux's [Conuter example](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter), and copied its code into my Gatsby project.
And the problem re-occurred, the component fails to re-render when the state changes (using one of Redux's examples!).

Only by using `this.forceUpdate()`, were I able to get the component re-render on state changes, and when I removed this line, it stopped re-rendering on state changes.

This is the Gatsby page I've created and the Redux's code I've copied into:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render - start",JSON.stringify(store.getState(),null,2))
    const { value, onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props
    return (
      <p>
        Clicked: {value} times
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>
          +
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onDecrement}>
          -
        </button>
      </p>
    )
  }
}

const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  console.log("reducer - start: ",state, JSON.stringify(action,null,2))
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(counter)

class TestPage extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Counter
        value={store.getState()}
        onIncrement={() => {
          store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
          // this.forceUpdate()
        }}
        onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}
      />)
  }
}

export default TestPage
```

Comment: I've also tried store.subscribe(), but the result was even weirder (only the TestPage's render method was called, and not its child Counter component's render method).

  constructor(p) {
    super(p)

    this.counter = (state = 0, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
          return state + 1
        case 'DECREMENT':
          return state - 1
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
    
    this.store = createStore(this.counter)
    this.store.subscribe(this.render.bind(this))
  }

Comment: I've verified that the TestPage's render method was called, and not its child Counter component's render method - by inserting a console.log() call as their first line. On page load - both were called, however as written above, when the state changed only the parent reported to log...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you correctly store.subsribe() ?

I made work it work like this.

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { store } from "./store";
import Counter from "./Counter";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Counter
        value={store.getState()}
        onIncrement={() => {
          store.dispatch({ type: "INCREMENT" });
        }}
        onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: "DECREMENT" })}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

render();
store.subscribe(render);
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT":
      return state + 1;
    case "DECREMENT":
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


export const   store = createStore(counter);
```

Counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Counter extends Component {

  render() {

    const { value, onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props
    return (
      <p>
        Value: {value} 
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onIncrement}>
          +
        </button>
        {' '}
        <button onClick={onDecrement}>
          -
        </button>
      </p>
    )
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

A sample codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-counter-2oftu

By the way using redux in react like this not makes much sense, we generally use react-redux package. You should definitely use react-redux package, after learning redux fundementals.

https://react-redux.js.org/

Comment: In the question's comment, you can see my unsuccessful try with store.subsribe().

However, my question was answered by your last paragraph, as I didn't know that React-Redux even existed. Of course that it solved this problem and some more...